# Cognito Forms: Why is the passport number format #,###

Tags: cognito-forms

I created a form with a passport number field.  When users of the form fill in the passport number field it says:

Passport Number must be formatted as #,###.

Why does the passport number require this format?

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms. We will need to collect some account information in order to better assist you with this. Could you please submit a Bug Report for the issue you are having?

Answer (score 4):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.  When you are building your form you can add any of the following types of fields:

[image]

In this case you added a Number field to your form to capture the Passport Number.  Number fields in Cognito are specifically designed to capture and store simple numbers (Integer, Decimal, or Percentages) and therefore require the user to enter values that are actually real numbers.

For Passport Number, your best choice would be to select Textbox, as passport numbers often contain letters and numbers.  This will eliminate the validation error you are seeing.